# Where Boxing can be used

Tags: java

[image: Picture from book]
i saw this example in book , where author is trying to tell the use of Boxing. I have problem in understanding the last lines i.e. "The code throws exception when it attempts to invoke doStuff(x) because x doesnt refer to Integer object." I didn't understand that why x is not an object of Integer Wrapper class. As if,  i defined it before as Static Integer x. Is this x variable is not a reference to Integer Wrapper class ?? . Moreover , why it throws "NullPointerException?"

Answer (score 7):

> I didn't understand that why x is not an object of Integer Wrapper class.

Because `x` was never initialized, so it has the default value: `null`.

> Moreover , why it throws "NullPointerException?"

Because [autounboxing is just a method call inserted by the compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to turn an `Integer` into an `int`: it calls [`Integer#intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29). But there is no instance, so it's just like trying to do this:

```
Integer x = null;
int someInt = x.intValue();
```

...which should be pretty obvious.

---

The steps involved in autounboxing, including this NPE behavior is specified in [the JLS § 5.1.8, *Unboxing Conversion.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) Happy reading!

Comment: Your hat is awesome. Oh damn I just got it too.

Answer (score 4):

When your code runs and you call `doStuff(x)`, `x` is `null` because you haven't initialized it. The compiler will produce byte code that calls `x.intValue()` to pass an `int` to your method. Since `x` is `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Integer being a reference type, a variable of type `Integer` can either contain `null` or a reference to an `Integer` object. They just want to say that if `x` is null, you can't convert it to an `int`.